# How to make a member of a struct dynamic

Tags: c

Say I have a struct of something and I want to make its members dynamic. I think the members should be something like this

```
char* id;
.....
```

following by a malloc to each member like this

```
books->id=(char*) malloc(size);
```

thou it seems when I try it my program crashed so I'm trying to understand what am I doing wrong

This is the part that I think that is relevant to my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define maxsize 512
typedef struct Books {
   char *id;
   char title[maxsize];
   char author[maxsize];
   char pages[maxsize];
   char year[maxsize];
   char subject[maxsize];
} book;
char* filename;
int libsize=4;
int bookcount=1;
...
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 if (argc < 1)
    return -1;
 filename=argv[1];
 FILE* fptr;
 char tempstring[maxsize],* token;
 int i=0,ch;
book *books;
fptr=fopen(filename,"r");
if(fptr==NULL)
return-1;
//this count how many books are in the file
  while(ch!= EOF){
    ch=fgetc(fptr);
    if(ch == '\n')
    ++bookcount;
  }
 fclose(fptr);
 while(libsize<bookcount){
    libsize *= 1.5;
 }
 books = (book*) malloc(libsize*sizeof(book));
 if(books==NULL)
    exit(-1);
 books->id=(char*)malloc(100);
 fptr=fopen(filename,"r");
 if(fptr==NULL)
    return-1;
//this gets all the books into the book array
  for(i=0;i<bookcount;i++){
    fgets(tempstring,maxsize,fptr);
    token=strtok(tempstring,",");
    strcpy(books[i].id,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].title,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].author,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].pages,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].year,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].subject,token);
   }
 fclose(fptr);
 printf("to add a book press 1\n");
 printf("to delete a book press 2\n");
 printf("to find a book press 3\n");
 printf("to print all books press 4\n");
 printf("to save library in a file press 5\n");
 printf("to add books from a file press 6\n");
 printf("to exit press 0\n");
 pick(books);
    return 1;
    }
void pick(book books[]){
    char input;
    scanf("%c",&input);
    switch (input){
    case '1':
        addbook(books);
        break;
    case '2':
        delbook(books);
        break; //pretty sure break isnt needed but it works so...eh
    case '3':
        srchbook(books);
        break;
    case '4':
        printbooks(books);
        break;
    case '5':
        printbooksf(books);
        break;
    case '6':
        addbookf(books);
        break;
    case '0':
        free(books);
        exit (1);
    case '\n':
        pick(books);
    default:
        printf("please enter a valid command\n");
        pick(books);
        break;
    }
}
```

edit2: added more of the code

edit3: found what was the problem what i did was trying to get to the pointer itself (i think) so the system flipped when i try to did it.
what i should have done was getting to each member array of the struct like that

```
for(i=0;i<bookcount;i++){
books[i].id=(char*)malloc(charcount);
books[i].title=(char*)malloc(charcount);
books[i].author=(char*)malloc(charcount);
books[i].pages=(char*)malloc(charcount);
books[i].year=(char*)malloc(charcount);
books[i].subject=(char*)malloc(charcount);
}
```

and not

```
books->id .....
```

Comment: Looks OK to me.The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: If you solved the problem may I suggest to post the answer below instead of in the question itself and mark it as accepted? It will help the community to find it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only `malloc` memory for `id` once. You need to do it for each book:

Like:

```
 // books->id=(char*)malloc(100);              Remove this line
 fptr=fopen(filename,"r");
 if(fptr==NULL)
    return-1;
//this gets all the books into the book array
  for(i=0;i<bookcount;i++){
    fgets(tempstring,maxsize,fptr);
    token=strtok(tempstring,",");
    books[i].id=(char*)malloc(100);    //        Add this line
    strcpy(books[i].id,token);
```

**BTW**

This code seems strange:

```
 while(libsize<bookcount){
    libsize *= 1.5;
 }
 books = (book*) malloc(libsize*sizeof(book));
```

why not simply do:

```
 books = (book*) malloc(bookcount*sizeof(book));
```

(note: you don't need to cast `malloc`)

Comment: number was intedned as a "magic number" but leave that be, even when i switch the lines the program still crashes, i have tried running it whith a static variable in the pointer and it works.
so i have no idea what im doing wrong here

Comment: @OmerGuttman - I can't say as you haven't posted a complete code example. However, the amount of memory allocated seems strange

Comment: edited in most of the code, other parts are just function that i belive not usefull becuse its crashing before its getting to them (fixed amout in the other variables)